# wilcox.test gives different results in when using formula

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

In R, why do wilcox.test gives different answerin case of formula and not using formula?

```
#running wilcox.test using formula 
r = wilcox.test(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars)
print(r$p.value)
[1] 0.001871391

#running wilcox.test by variables
s= wilcox.test(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$am)
print(s$p.value)
[1] 2.74978e-12

s= wilcox.test(mtcars$am, mtcars$mpg)
print(s$p.value)
[1] 2.74978e-12
```

Why is p-value is different in these two cases?

Answer (score 4):

In the formula, case one, is comparing the 'mpg' variable subsetted with the 'am' variable.  In this case a vector of 19 values versus a vector of 13 values.
In the non-formula example, one is comparing the 'mpg' vector vs 'am' vector.  This is two 32 values vectors.

```
 wilcox.test(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$am==0], mtcars$mpg[mtcars$am==1])
```

This will provide the same result as the formula format.

Comment: code gives error : `Error in wilcox.test.default(mtcars[mtcars$mpg == 0], mtcats[mtcars$mpg ==  : 'x' must be numeric`

Comment: @cNinja, sorry slight error in formula, corrected and now provides the same answer as the formula format.